# Ionic App just freezes while initiating d3.js axis. No error messages

Tags: ios, cordova, d3.js, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic/Cordova APP that uses D3.js. Some days ago the app started to freeze when the user enter the page that draw the graph, then he needs to force closing the app.

It happen exactly on this line:

```
chart.xAxis.call(chart.axis.x)
```

**chart.xAxis** is the svg group and **char.axis.x** is a d3.axisBottom().scale(chart.scales.x)

There is no errors on the console and running on Xcode everything (CPU, memory, etc) is OK.

Have you ever encountered something like this?

Comment: I have discovered that the bug is on the time scale..
I'm passing the two dates, the first is set in the regular brazilian time (BRT) and the second is set in the daylight saving brazilian time (BRST)..

Now, I just need to discover how to fix it. Someone?

Comment: I used the `d3.scaleUtc()` to solve my problem, it's not the best option at all but as I'm using just the day and month, it works.
https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleUtc